# How to get test coverage info when testing a typescript vscode extension with @vscode/test-cli

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, vscode-extensions

I am developing a vscode extension in Typescript and I am running unit tests using the new experimental client package `@vscode/test-cli`.
This is my `.vscode-test.mjs`:

```
import { defineConfig } from "@vscode/test-cli";

export default defineConfig({
  files: "out/test/**/*.test.js",
  
});
```

and I run the test with `pnpm run test` where the `test` script is:

```
"pretest": "pnpm run compile && pnpm run lint",
"test": "vscode-test",
```

I tried using `nyc` to collect the test coverage, but I can't make it work.

I have the following `.nycrc`:

```
{
    "extends": "@istanbuljs/nyc-config-typescript",
    "include": [
      "src/**/*.ts",
      "out/**/*.js"
    ],
    "exclude": [
      "src/**/*.test.js"
    ],
    "reporter": [
      "text-summary",
      "html",
      "lcov"
    ],
    "report-dir": "coverage"
  }
```

and the script:

```
"coverage": "nyc pnpm run test",
```

But I get:

```
=============================== Coverage summary ===============================
Statements   : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
Branches     : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
Functions    : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
Lines        : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
================================================================================
```

How can I make nyc work with `@vscode/test-cli`?